# scrapy: avoid circular re-crawling

Tags: python, scrapy

i am building a scraper for attractions nearby hotels in tripAdvisor,
the scraper will parse urls like this : http://www.tripadvisor.com/AttractionsNear-g55711-d1218038-oa30-Dallas_Addison_Marriott_Quorum_By_the_Galleria-Dallas_Texas.html

i wrote two rules to get these urls, the second one is for the next attractions page for the destination urls:

```
Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(".*AttractionsNear-g.*",),
                           restrict_xpaths=('.//div[@class="nearby_links wrap"]/a',), unique=True),
         callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(".*AttractionsNear-g.*",),
                           restrict_xpaths=('.//div[@class="pgLinks"]/a[contains(@class, "pageNext")]',), unique=True),
         callback='parse_item', follow=True),
```

but in my destination url the first rule is valid, and the scraper will re-crawl to already parsed urls and will begin the process from start.

i tried to avoid the circular crawling by DownloaderMiddleware

```
class LocationsDownloaderMiddleware(object):
def process_request(self, request, spider):
    if(request.url.encode('ascii', errors='ignore') in deny_domains):
        return IgnoreRequest()
    else: return None
```

and by managing deny_domains list- in the response parsing

```
 def parse_item(self, response):
    deny_domains.append(response.url.encode('ascii', errors='ignore'))
```

but now this middleware is blocking every url i want to parse.

How can i manage it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SgmlLinkExtractor` is discontinued, you should use `scrapy.linkextractors.LinkExtractor` instead.

Now your rules should look like this:

```
rules = (
    Rule(
        LinkExtractor(
            restrict_xpaths=['xpath_to_category'],
            allow=('regex_for_links')
        ),
        follow=True,
    ),
    Rule(
        LinkExtractor(
            restrict_xpaths=['xpath_to_items'],
            allow=('regex_to_links')
        ),
        callback='some_parse_method',
    ),
)
```

When you specify `follow=True` it means that you are not using `callback`, but instead you are just specifying that those links should be "followed" and the rules still apply. You can check the docs [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules).

Also it won't make duplicate requests because scrapy is filtering that.

Comment: in my case i need callback and follow together because there are pages i parse and want to continue to the next page. if scrapy is filtering my requests there is no problem. thanks